# INSERT TABLE using php variable

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

What is the correct syntax for the `SQL INSERT INTO` when using a php variable for table name. I have tried everything and it won't insert when I use php variable.

**This is what I have so far.  is this right?**

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$table." (`Name`) VALUES ('A')";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

**if I switch `$table` to the actual table name, it wor**ks

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO 'myTable' ('Name') Values ('A')";
```

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: what error you are getting in executing the query?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me fine

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "stack_over_flow";
$con = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}
else
{
    //echo ("Connect Successfully");
}
```

**When Table Name is Variable**

```
$DB_TBLName = "abc"; 
$sql_ac_valuee    = "INSERT INTO $DB_TBLName (a, b ,c) VALUES "."('10','20','30')"; 
if ($con->query($sql_ac_valuee) === TRUE) {
}
else{
    echo "Error: " . $sql_ac_valuee . "<br>" . $con->error;
}
```

**When Use direct Table Name**

```
$sql_ac_valuee    = "INSERT INTO abc (a, b ,c) VALUES "."('10','20','30')"; 
if ($con->query($sql_ac_valuee) === TRUE) {
}
else{
    echo "Error: " . $sql_ac_valuee . "<br>" . $con->error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO $tname (place,dis,p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4,p_5,p_6) VALUES('$name','$discription','$bfile','$file1','$file2','$file3','$file4','$file5')"; 
$result =mysqli_query($link,$query); 
if(!$result){echo mysqli_error($link);?>
```

This was my code and the output is:

> Skardu.You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(place,dis,p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4,p_5,p_6) VALUES('Sundus','Few people can afford the T' at line 1

its work fine when i use skardu instead of varible